# How to modify Color Swatches From vertical to horizontal in Layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, swatches, color-swatches

hi I need to modify magento layered navigation colour swatches from vertical............[image]

to horizontal....[image]

But I did not got any idea...like which file is responsible for this...Basically...i need to modify vertical to horizontal....
pls help..

Comment: can you please share me that url

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change some styling to achieve that. To help you with that, we will need you to show us the template code responsible.

To find the template file for that, you will need to turn on template path hints.

1. Log into the magento back-end admin
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or
   store view.
5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a
   new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path
   hints.

[Source](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12659-How-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-in-magento)

Template path hints are little tags which would lie on top of your shop frontend. These little tags enable you to view where exactly the code of a specific element is stored within your file structure.